# WPF loading animation on a separate UI thread? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, animation, loading

Okay, I have a loading animation that runs while a large DataTable is populated to let the user know that the program has not frozen. I have the animation working fine, but it freezes while the DataTable is updatingv as well. Is there some way to have multiple UI threads, so that the animation will continue to run while the DataTable is loading information?

**EDIT: Current code is below.**

```
private void CreateFileTable()
{
    file_data = new DataSet();
    data_table = new DataTable();
    file_data.Tables.Add(data_table);

    DataColumn tempCol = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Ext", typeof(string));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Created", typeof(Label));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Modified", typeof(Label));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Accessed", typeof(Label));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    tempCol = new DataColumn("Location", typeof(string));
    data_table.Columns.Add(tempCol);

    File_List.ItemsSource = file_data.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}

private void PopulateDirectories(string[] directories)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
    {
        DirectoryInfo tempDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directories[i]);

        bool isSystem = ((tempDirInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System);

        if (!isSystem)
        {
            DataRow tempRow = data_table.NewRow();
            tempRow["File Name"] = tempDirInfo.Name;
            tempRow["Ext"] = "";
            tempRow["Size"] = "";

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempDirInfo.CreationTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempDirInfo.CreationTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Created"] = tempLabel;

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempDirInfo.LastWriteTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempDirInfo.LastWriteTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Modified"] = tempLabel;

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempDirInfo.LastAccessTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempDirInfo.LastAccessTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Accessed"] = tempLabel;
            tempRow["Location"] = tempDirInfo.FullName;

            data_table.Rows.Add(tempRow);
        }
    }
}

private void PopulateFiles(string[] files)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo tempFileInfo = new FileInfo(files[i]);

        bool isSystem = ((File.GetAttributes(files[i]) & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System);

        if (!isSystem)
        {
            DataRow tempRow = data_table.NewRow();
            tempRow["File Name"] = tempFileInfo.Name;
            tempRow["Ext"] = tempFileInfo.Extension;

            int fileSize = (int)tempFileInfo.Length;

            if (fileSize > 1048576)
            {
                tempRow["Size"] = "" + fileSize / 1048576 + " MB";
            }
            else if (fileSize > 1024)
            {
                tempRow["Size"] = "" + fileSize / 1024 + " KB";
            }
            else
            {
                tempRow["Size"] = "" + fileSize + " B";
            }

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempFileInfo.CreationTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempFileInfo.CreationTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Created"] = tempLabel;

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempFileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempFileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Modified"] = tempLabel;

            tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
            tempLabel.Content = tempFileInfo.LastAccessTime.ToLongDateString() + ", " + tempFileInfo.LastAccessTime.ToLongTimeString();

            tempRow["Accessed"] = tempLabel;
            tempRow["Location"] = tempFileInfo.DirectoryName;

            data_table.Rows.Add(tempRow);
        }
    }
}

private string GetSelectedPath(TreeViewItem selectedNode)
{
    return selectedNode.Tag as string;
}

private void PopulateFileList()
{
    PopulateDirectories(Directory.GetDirectories(GetSelectedPath((TreeViewItem)Dir_Tree.SelectedItem)));
    PopulateFiles(Directory.GetFiles(GetSelectedPath((TreeViewItem)Dir_Tree.SelectedItem)));
}

private void UpdateFileList()
{
    LoadingWheel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    CreateFileTable();
    PopulateFileList();
    TxtFoundCount.Text = "Files/Folders Found: " + File_List.Items.Count;

    LoadingWheel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

I have tried using the BackgroundWorker and calling the UpdateFileList() method inside it, but I'm not having any luck.

**EDIT: Below is my code for the BackgroundWorker.**

```
private BackgroundWorker bgWorker1;

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    bgWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker1_DoWork);
    bgWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

private void bgWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        PopulateFileList();
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => PopulateFileList()));
    }
}

private void bgWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    TxtFoundCount.Text = "Files/Folders Found: " + File_List.Items.Count;
    LoadingWheel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void UpdateFileList()
{
    LoadingWheel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    CreateFileTable();
    bgWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I have a SelectionChanged event on a TreeView that calls InitializeBackgroundWorker() and UpdateFileList(). The list loads still, and I get no errors, but the loading animation never becomes visible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your background worker stuff?

Comment: I took the BackgroundWorker code back out because it was more code and didn't help any. I can put it back in, but I'm pretty sure I did it wrong.

Comment: In this case, you would probably call the background worker's RunWorkerAsync function from UpdateFileList, after "turning on" the LoadingWheel.  Move the two function calls to bgWorker_DoWork, the update to the TextBlock to bgWorker_ProgressChanged, and turning off the LoadingWheel to bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted.  See updated answer.

Comment: I've posted my code for the BackgroundWorker above. I'll try what you said and see if it helps any! Thanks again for taking the time to work with me on this!

Comment: Nope - that's wrong.  See my updated answer below.  By calling the Invoke stuff in the DoWork method, you are just moving the work back to the UI thread.

Comment: If I don't use the Invoke I get an error message telling me that I can't call the function because it belongs to another thread. I'm using multithreading for my TreeView, so maybe something there is causing problems...?

Comment: That is correct - the DoWork function runs on a different thread (and is the point of the bgworker).  Like my example in the answer, you need to put the data into a temporary data structure, and pass that data structure to the ProgressChanged (as the UserState) and/or RunWorkerCompleted (as the e.Result at the end of DoWork).  Please create a new dummy project, and copy/paste the code I've provided to see how it works.

Comment: Okay, I used the format of your example and finally got it to work for the most part. It still pauses at the end of the loading, but it's the best I can get. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is only one UI thread.  What you need to do is to load the data in the DataTable on a different thread.

If you want to show progress to the DataTable loading along the way (either directly, or through a ProgressBar or some other mechanism), the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is a fairly straight-forward way to do that.

**UPDATE: Very Simple Background Worker example**
Here is a fairly simple example.  It adds 100 random numbers to a collection, pausing the thread for a short time between each to simulate a long loading process.  You can simply cut and paste this into a test project of your own to see it work.

The thing to notice is that the heavy lifting (the stuff that takes a while) is done in the DoWork, while all UI updates are done in ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted.  In fact, a separate list (numbers) is created in the DoWork handler because the global mNumbers collection is on the UI thread, and can't interact in the DoWork handler.

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="btnGenerateNumbers"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Generate Numbers" />
```

**C# Code-Behind**

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
ObservableCollection<int> mNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bgWorker.DoWork += 
        new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
    bgWorker.ProgressChanged += 
        new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    btnGenerateNumbers.Click += (s, e) => UpdateNumbers();

    this.DataContext = this;
}

void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    lstItems.Opacity = 1d;
    btnGenerateNumbers.IsEnabled = true;
}

void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<int> numbers = (List<int>)e.UserState;
    foreach (int number in numbers)
    {
         mNumbers.Add(number);
    }

    progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>(10);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        // Add a random number
        numbers.Add(rnd.Next());            

        // Sleep from 1/8 of a second to 1 second
        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(125, 1000));

        // Every 10 iterations, report progress
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
        {
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(i, numbers.ToList<int>());
            numbers.Clear();
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<int> NumberItems
{
    get { return mNumbers; }
}

private void UpdateNumbers()
{
    btnGenerateNumbers.IsEnabled = false;
    mNumbers.Clear();
    progress.Value = 0;
    progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    lstItems.Opacity = 0.5;

    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: I posted my current code above. I tried implementing the BackgroundWorker with it, but had no luck. It still froze the UI like it did before.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little test program which shows the use of the Dispatcher class. It just requires a WPF-Window and a ListBox with Name "listBox". Should be easy to apply this solution to your problem.

```
    public void Populate() {
        // for comparison, freezing the ui thread
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            listBox.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private delegate void AddItemDelegate(int item);
    public void PopulateAsync() {
        // create a new thread which is iterating the elements
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate() {
            // inside the new thread: iterate the elements
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                // use the dispatcher to "queue" the insertion of elements into the UI-Thread
                // DispatcherPriority.Background ensures Animations have a higher Priority and the UI does not freeze
                // possible enhancement: group the "jobs" to small units to enhance the performance
                listBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AddItemDelegate(delegate(int item) {
                    listBox.Items.Add(item);
                }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, i);
            }
        })).Start();
    }
```