# WPF - Loading Window inside User Control

Tags: wpf, loading

I use DevExpress tab control.

At the moment, when a user does something that takes some time, such as generating something etc, I have a window come up with text "Saving ..." that essentially disables the MainWindow while the operation is in progress.

This obviously doesn't let them continue on doing something else in the meantime.

I'd like that they could simply click on another tab and do something else.

An example done in paint :) :

User presses 'Do Something' button.
Tab1 is now disabled until 'Something' is done.
Tab2 however, is not.
[image]

Ideally it hovers over the usercontrol rather than pushing stuff out of the way/making them invisible.

EDIT: The text needs to be editable. I.e. If I'm looping through products for example, ideally I write 'Processing Product 0/100'

Comment: Look at the ChildWindow on the Extended Toolkit. (or BusyIndicator for that matter)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806535/wpf-loading-animation-on-a-separate-ui-thread-c

Comment: I've already done the backgroundworker approach, but I'm using a Window with text "Processed Product 0/100" for example. This, however, can only have another Window as a parent (such as MainWindow) - which currently locks out the MainWindow. I'd like it to lock out a single tab instead of the entire thing.
Question is more of a "What control can I use to do this" rather than a how to update a control with progress.