# C# WPF - Loading screen modal

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF Application with C#.

In this application there is a button which opens a new window/view.
When this view opens it displays some data. At the same time new data is being retrieved and the view gets updated with this new data after a few seconds. I do not want the old data to be shown, so the view should just be loading until the new data is retrieved.

So I would like to have a loading modal (something like a pop-up) that is displayed in the middle of the screen until the data has been retrieved. Also the parent view should be frozen/disabled while loading the data.

My idea was to create a modal and open it (via .ShowDialog())  while the data is being retrieved. But when doing my research I found no possibility to automatically open the modal while the data is being retrieved. I only found how to open the modal via a button.

Does someone have an idea?

I basically just need a loading bar, but the loading bar should just be simple modal with just a small text (like "Wait till data is retrieved").

Comment: I would advice to check thread's.
First you should use a thread to load the data besides the UI Thread, or it will block the UI  Thread.
Its a old topic but it will give you an idea
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806535/wpf-loading-animation-on-a-separate-ui-thread-c

Comment: That feature/control is often called "BusyIndicator": https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=wpf%20busyindicator

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, after doing additional research on the topics you've told me, I managed to get it working. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use [SplashScreen](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radsplashscreen/getting-started), where you can show any picture at any time...

```
var splashScreen = new SplashScreen("load.png");
splashScreen.Show(false);

//data retrieve code here

splashScreen.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

You can make image out of any text using Photoshop or similar tools and use it as a 'Resource' in the WPF Project and then display it using the above code snippet...

Comment: Did you try this before posting?

Comment: I use it often, while retrieving big data from database...

Comment: And it doesn't lock up the UI? The pattern you're suggestion wouldn't allow the UI to show the splash screen until the data has finished loading.